# Render method not working

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a little game, I've made two games before this one, so I thought I wouldn't get too much trouble with it.

So I made the render method for the player, it looks like this:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    switch(objState) {
       case Static:
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(50, 50, width, height);
            //g.drawImage(staticimg, x, y, null);
            break;
        case WalkRight:
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            //g.drawImage(walkright, x, y, null);
            break;
        case WalkLeft:
            g.setColor(Color.cyan);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            //g.drawImage(walkleft, x, y, null);
            break;
        case Stop:
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            //g.drawImage(stop, x, y, null);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But the player is not rendered, I added a sysout at the top of the render method to check if it's actually getting called, and I found out that it is.

The objState is equal to ObjectState.Static, so the first case should be called.

I created a render method for the map which used the exact same Graphics as this class does, and that worked fine, so the Graphics doesn't seem to be the problem either. I tried adding a little bit of code outside of the switch statement which would do the same thing as in the first case, but still nothing is being rendered

Comment: Is `Static` a String? Is this render method in the ObjectState class?

Comment: @johmsp The render method is in a class called Player, and static is an enum in ObjectState

Comment: What are width and height when this gets called?

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused. If the enum is in ObjectState, wouldn't you have to get it by doing ObjectState.Static? Does Player extend ObjectState? Is Static an enum or is Static one of the elements in the ObjectState enum?

Comment: @johmsp Static is one of the elements in the ObjectState enum

Comment: @Frecklefoot Both is 64

Comment: Is it always skipping every state and jumping to `default`? Place sysout statements in each `case`.

Comment: Have you tried printing what `objState` equals before the switch? And have you tried putting a print method in the Static case to see if it makes it to there?

Comment: @Frecklefoot It never reaches `default`

Comment: @johmsp I tried adding a little bit of code that would render the exact same thing as in the first case, but still, nothing is being rendered, and objState is equal to Static

Comment: I would also check the values of `x` and `y`, but I assume you've done that. Check when you are calling `render()`. Depending on where you call it, its rendering may be overridden by other drawing.

Comment: I would recommend using the debugger in your IDE, if you are using one and it is available.

Comment: @Frecklefoot Completely forgot about that, I was rendering the map after the player, so that was causing the problem, thanks!

Comment: It happens to the best of us. : ) Congratulations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little chat with [Frecklefoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611716/frecklefoot) I realised that I was rendering the map after the player, causing it to overlap the player and therefore it was not visible.